# I have the driver, class.forname() doesn't throw exception but 'No Suitable Driver for MySQL '

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I know this kind of question pop up a lot but I needed to ask this question.


I have the jar file containing mysql jdbc driver , namely mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar.
I opened this jar file and confirmed that this jar file does contain com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.class.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Connection");
```

This does not throw any exceptions.

When I try to get a connection with the code below however I get an exception.

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,dbUNM,dbUPW);
```

(I'm not sure if it's wise to put the connection URL uphere)

I get this

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:xxx....
```

also I see

```
    Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:624)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:823)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:794)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:1134)
```

Can you point out what I'm doing wrong ? Thank you : )

Comment: What is your connection string?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between 'connection' and 'driver'? Not a real question.

Comment: If it's not a real question, what is it then ? Yes, I understand the difference. I just didn't see it. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to load the driver class using Class.forName - try the following line of code

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Comment: Oh god, I'm so blushed. Thanks !!